# Can't change my button's apperance

Tags: html

We have tried to make a cool button but we can't. We tried for 2 hours and we just cant make it worked. We've looked at a lot of different guides and nothing is working. Now we are coming here for help

```css
 <style>
   .button {
    background-color: darkcyan;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
 font-family: hacked;
 
 
}

  .sub {
  position: relative;
}
.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}

  
  
  .itmHolder:nth-child(2),
.itmHolder:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.og {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}



 </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Our Future</title>
 </head>
 <!--Baggrunds farve-->
 <body bgcolor="#212f3c">
 
 <!--Hovedskriften-->
     <font size=40><center><h1 style="font-family:blowbrush;">Future</font></center></h1><form action="side2.html">
  
  
   <div class="og">
  <div class="itmHolder">

    <div class="sub">
      <button type="button" class="Button">About us</button>
      <button type="button" class="Button">Buy now</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

2nd line of your code, change '.button' to '.Button'

Answer (score 1):

CSS are case sensitive, change `.button` to `.Button` or change class name on your button.

btw, `center`, `font size` are deprecated, use css instead like:

```
.your-class-font {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.your-class-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.Button {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: hacked;
}

h1 {
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;
}

.sub {
  position: relative;
}

.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}

.itmHolder:nth-child(2),
.itmHolder:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.og {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Our Future</title>
</head>
<!--Baggrunds farve-->

<body bgcolor="#212f3c">

  <!--Hovedskriften-->


  <h1 style="font-family:blowbrush;">Future </h1>


  <form action="side2.html">


    <div class="og">
      <div class="itmHolder">

        <div class="sub">
          <button type="button" class="Button">About us</button>
          <button type="button" class="Button">Buy now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```